# Simple SQL query for delete

Tags: sql, h2

I use H2 embedded db and have some table with field "time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME'.

How I can delete all row from table where CURRENT_TIME - table.time > 10 min?

Comment: What particular detail is causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like the query below.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE TIME_FIELD > (DATEADD('MINUTE',-10, CURRENT_TIME)))
```

**EDIT 1**: The above query shows greater than, I believe you want less than

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE TIME_FIELD < (DATEADD('MINUTE',-10, CURRENT_TIME)))
```

**EDIT 2**: For more information about Functions of H2 databases you can look at the link below.

[Functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html)